# C++ namespace causes compile error no return type, default int is used

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces

so I'm writting a engine using opengl and I had everything in a namespace called

```
namespace doge {

}
```

I have a file called "header.h" which all my files will #include, in this "header.h" I did

```
namespace doge{
    using namespace std;
};
```

then I have a "shader.h" which defines

```
#include "header.h"

namespace doge {
    class shader {
    private:
        // members
    public:
        GLuint createProgram();
        GLuint addShader();
        // other functions
    };
};
```

then in "shader.cpp"

```
#include "shader.h"

GLuint doge::shader::createProgram() {
    // code
}

GLuint doge::shader::addShader() {
    // code
}
```

I have a "engine.h" which integrates everything so in "engine.h" I have

```
#include "header.h"
#include "shader.h"
#include "other stuffs"

namespace doge {
    class Engine {

    };
};
```

I got a compile error at addShader in "shader.cpp" telling me that addShader does not have a return type defined so int is used (sorry I can't post the actual error message because I've already fixed the problem and reversing it is tiring).

GLuint is included in "GL/glew.h" which is included in "header.h", it is defined as

```
typedef unsigned int GLuint
```

with no namespace

I know namespace in c++ is complicated so I removed

```
 using namespace std;
```

in "header.h", added std:: infront of everyting and everything works

I just want to know why did this happen? thanks in advance

Comment: What's `GLuint`, where is it included?

Comment: @songyuanyao GLuint is included in GL/glew.h which is included in "header.h" it's not in any namespace

Comment: Did you put `#include <GL/glew.h>` inside `namespace dodge {...}`?

Comment: @RSahu no I did not

Comment: Does the problem come back if you simply add back that `using namespace std;` line?  Seems like a red herring to me.  The _shader.cpp_ file should have first errored on `createProgram()`.  Either you're not showing the _first_ error, or something else happened and you accidentally fixed it later.  But it's good that you did remove the _std_ namespace import, which just encourages lazy programming and awful bugs.

Comment: @paddy I know the problem have something to do with name hidding, I've seen a similar problem before. there is no error on the first createProgram which was why I thought was really weird.